# Prove unit ball $C([0,1])$ is not compact.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For a homework assignment, I was asked to prove that the closed unit ball is not compact in $C([0,1])$ with the sup norm $|| \cdot ||_\infty$.

Ergo, I decided to show that it is not sequentially compact.

Here are the two examples I devised:

i) simply, $f_n = \{x^n\}$. Since they converge point-wise to a non-continuous function, they do not converge uniformly... the only convergence in this space. Ergo, no subsequence converges.

ii) Let $$f_n (x) = = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       -nx+1 & : x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]\\
       0 & : x \in (\frac{1}{n},1]
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

Both examples satisfy $||f_n|| \leq 1$ for all $n$, ergo these examples serve as proof the closed unit ball is not compact.

Do both of these examples work? Are there any other standard examples?

Comment: Depending on the situation, the "Ergo, no subsequence converges." may need elaboration. Other standard examples include $f_n(x) = \sin (nx)$ and their ilk.